# I am not able to launch Firefox 0.19.1 in Selenium 3.10.0

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, geckodriver

I am not able to launch Firefox. I am using Selenium 3.10.0 and Firefox version is 0.19.1

Code :

```
public class SampleClass 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\geckodriver-v0.19.1-win32\\geckodriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=pvK5WsHVGKSIX7qArmA");
        }
    }
```

Error :

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:20603
Build info: version: '3.10.0', revision: '176b4a9', time: '2018-03-02T19:10:56.039Z'
```

Comment: either the selenium server isn't running, or it's not running on port 20603.

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stack trace.

Comment: Did you try updating your FF version?

Comment: is the selenium server running?

Answer (score 0):

Many errors are the result of drivers and browsers being out of date. Please ensure you are running the latest.

Update your GeckoDriver to latest version: (should be v20)
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.20.0/geckodriver-v0.20.0-win32.zip

Update your Firefox to latest version: (Should be v59.0.*)
https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/

Update your Selenium Server: (Java - Should be v3.11.0)
https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/